# (Angular) Working with an array of data from API

Tags: angular, api, angular-reactive-forms, formarray

Regarding some data fetched through a service for an API. The data (loungers) is received and shown in a table on the front-end application (Angular), where I put checkboxes for each row. The idea is that the user should be able to check the boxes which he would like to add to his reservation.

The API shall take a reservation model with one-to-many loungers, however I can not for the life of me make it work. When checking the browsers console the array of loungers is either 'Undefined' or I can only make it show one of the 3 attributes (ID, Zone, or Type), where the whole object is needed for the reservation object.

I gotta say I've aimed to high with this project, since my experience with JS/TS and HTML too is very lacking and this comes to show now. I've googled and tried changing a lot of stuff, but am really at a loss here. I'm sure there's some simple fix for this, that someone with more experience will be able to point out. Thanks!

**reservation.ts** *(model)*

```
import { Lounger } from "./lounger";

export class Reservation {
    id: string;
    date: string;
    startTime: string;
    endTime: string;
    userId: string;
    loungers: Lounger[];
}
```

**lounger.ts** *(model)*

```
export class Lounger {
    id: string;
    type: string;
    zone: string;
}
```

**add-edit-component.ts**

```
export class AddEditComponent implements OnInit {
    reservationForm: FormGroup;
    id: string;
    isAddMode: boolean;
    loading = false;
    submitted = false;
    user: User;
    reservation: Reservation;
    loungersFromApi: Lounger[];

    constructor(
        private formBuilder: FormBuilder,
        private route: ActivatedRoute,
        private router: Router,
        private reservationService: ReservationService,
        private alertService: AlertService,
        private accountService: AccountService,
        private loungerService: LoungerService
    ) {
        this.user = this.accountService.userValue;
    }
    

    ngOnInit() {
        this.id = this.route.snapshot.params['id'];
        this.isAddMode = !this.id;

        this.loungerService.getAll()
        .pipe(first())
        .subscribe(x => this.loungersFromApi = x);

        this.reservationForm = this.formBuilder.group({
            date: ['', Validators.required],
            startTime: ['', Validators.required],
            endTime: ['', Validators.required],
            userId: [this.user.id],
            loungers: this.formBuilder.array([], Validators.required)
        });
    }

onCheckboxChange(e) {
    const loungers: FormArray = this.reservationForm.get('loungers') as FormArray;

    if (e.target.checked) {
        loungers.push(new FormControl(e.target.value));
    } else {
        let i: number = 0;
        loungers.controls.forEach((item: FormControl) => {
            if (item.value == e.target.value) {
                loungers.removeAt(i);
                return;
            }
            i++;
        });
    }
}

get f() { return this.reservationForm.controls; }
```

}

**add-edit.component.html**

```
<form [formGroup]="reservationForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">

<div>
         <div *ngFor="let lounger of loungersFromApi; let i=index">
                <label>
                  <input type="checkbox" [value]="lounger.id" (change)="onCheckboxChange($event)" />
                  {{lounger.id}}
                </label>
              </div>
        </div>
    </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

While you could add an object as a FormControl, I would add it as a FormGroup instead.

We can use `find` to compare the value of event.target.value in your `loungersFromApi` to match the `id` (which you are using). The template stays the same as you have, but just a few changes in your `onCheckboxChange` to add the FormGroups:

```ts
onCheckboxChange(e) {
  const loungers: FormArray = this.reservationForm.get(
    'loungers'
  ) as FormArray;

  if (e.target.checked) {
    // use find to find the matching item
    const item = this.loungersFromApi.find(x => x.id === e.target.value);
    if (item) {
      // push a formgroup instead with the whole object
      loungers.push(this.formBuilder.group(item));
    }
  } else {
    let i: number = 0;
    loungers.controls.forEach((item: FormControl) => {
      // again, find the item in your array by id
      if (item.value.id == e.target.value) {
        loungers.removeAt(i);
        return;
      }
      i++;
    });
  }
}
```

Here's a cleaned up version of your code. Just as a suggestion, look at the code presented in Stackblitz I linked, as your issue is only with the checkboxes, that is really what you only need to show for it to be a minimal reproducible example. You will more likely get answers if the issue is clearly presented and all unneccessary code has been stripped away. No one wants to sift through a bunch of code to try and find the issue... Well... I just did :D

**[STACKBLITZ](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-m8zwrx?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)** for your reference

Comment: Hi there and thank you so very much for your time! I tried you solution with changing the onCheckboxChange method, but unfortunately it still won't work.

This is the output in browser: 
https://imgur.com/a/wMMZ1Gj

I will keep on trying, but please do return if you can see what is wrong. Your effort is appreciated!

Comment: @t_hound I gave you a working sample on stackblitz, if you are facing issues, please fork the stackblitz with the current code you have and reproduce the issue. Cannot otherwise help, as it is working in the demo I made.

Comment: Sorry for reaching. I tried commenting out the getAll method from the service and just used the static array - and then it works. So the problem must be with the service/Observable object.

Comment: You need to debug, check what you are getting from the backend, do the values match, do the properies match. Dev tools are great for this. And console logs all over the place to see what you are working with :)

Comment: Hi AJT82. I used your tip and made console logs a lot of places. The issue seemed to be this line:

const item = this.loungersFromApi.find(x => x.id === e.target.value);

Where changing from 3 to 2 equality signs now makes it all work as supposed to. Thank you very much for your help and a good day to you!

Comment: Then it means that you have a type mismatch, you were trying to compare string value, for example `"3"` with number `3`. You should strive to not fallback to only checking `==`, instead convert the string to number before comparing. Type checking is important ;)

Comment: Yes, by googling the difference on 1-3 equal signs I also came to that realization. Perhaps it would've shown had I worked in the other project, where I got strict mode set to true. Again, thanks for your time and help.